# Why is the Wifi symbol gone?

Tags: wireless-networking, icloud

Yesterday, I installed iCloud on my Toshiba Satellite laptop.
The wifi was connected at the time of installation, and the system prompted to reboot the device to finish installing iCloud.

When restarted, the wifi symbol disappeared but the Wireless adapter was updated and working fine. The Wifi symbol does not appear on the bottom bar, and when clicking on the "Network and Sharing Center", it states "The dependency service or group failed to start".

Answer (score 0):

Try to reset IP/TCP stack
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/299357/how-to-reset-tcp-ip-by-using-the-netshell-utility

Open Start. Type 'msconfig' and hit enter. Select 'Normal Startup' as the startup selection option and restart the PC.
Normal startup force loads all drivers